# Refactoring get request to use key value pairs (react saving data into state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React/json newbie here!

I had a get request which worked fine, but I need to change the get request to structure my data in a key value pair way.

Old approach (working) - Returns an object array of 22 documents with all types of key value pairs:

```
  public getDocuments() {

    axios
      .get("https://bpk.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='owstaxIdFavouritex0020COlour:",
        { params:{},
          headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        })
      .then(response => {

        this.setState({
          document: response.data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results
        });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
```

New approach (Not working) - This needs to return an object array of 22 documents with 4 types of key value pairs for each document:

```
 public getDocuments() {

    axios
      .get("https://bpk.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='owstaxIdFavouritex0020COlour:",
        { params:{},
          headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        })
      .then(response => {

        let documentsData = response.data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;

        this.setState({
          documents {
            name: documentsData.Cells.results[36].Value,
            path: documentsData.Cells.results[6].Value,
            view: documentsData.Cells.results[3].Value, 
            site: documentsData.Cells.results[6].Value
          }
        });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
```

I have tried my best but I have quite a few syntax errors. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: `documents: {` - missing colon

Comment: Fixed it thank you!